Stereographic projection inverse is $C^{1,1}$?
for a step of my proof I need to be sure that the inverse of the stereographic projection $\sigma$ is of class $C^{1,1}$, i.e. continously differentiable and both $\sigma$ and $D\sigma$ are Lipschitz continous. Here we have $\sigma: S^2\setminus  \{(0,0,1)\}\rightarrow R^2, x\mapsto (\frac{2x_1}{1-x_3},\frac{2x_2}{1-x_3})$ and $\sigma^{-1}:R^2\rightarrow S^2\setminus\{(0,0,1)\},x\mapsto (\frac{2x_1}{|x|^2+1},\frac{2x_2}{|x|^2+1},\frac{|x|^2-1}{|x|^2+1})$.
While $\sigma^{-1}\in C^1$ is clear, I do not see why $\sigma^ {-1}$ and $D\sigma^{-1}$ are lipschitz. Can you help me out on this?

If you calculate the second partial derivatives of $\sigma^{-1}$ you will see that they are all continuous and bounded, making $D\sigma^{-1}$ uniformly Lipschitz. For example $$\partial^2_{x_1x_1}\sigma^{-1}_1=2x_1(8x_1^2 /(|x|^2 +1)^3-2/(|x|^2+1)^2)-8x_1/(|x|^2+1)^2$$
is uniformly continuous and bounded.
